# Open source projects using IoC

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am looking for good real-world examples of IoC in actual .NET software projects that use any of the common (or even uncommon) IoC containers to resolve dependency graphs more complex than two or three abstractions. Most examples and explanations are intentionally kept simple and rarely use more than one concept at a time, which makes it difficult to get a good idea of when to use what special construct (e.g. Abstract Factory, Facade, Aggregate Service etc.) or how to use object lifetime management in practice.

I was hoping to find project references on the respective IoC containers' web sites, but so far have been unsuccessful. There are a few questions here on that topic, but those are older and don't have a lot of useful answers.

Edit: If you vote for closing this question, please at least leave a comment stating why you (obviously) think it's not a valid question here and where else you think I should ask this rather than on SO.

Comment: i found the following two projects to be quite useful for me: 1) http://www.sharparchitecture.net/ 2) http://kigg.codeplex.com/ it's web app both though

Comment: I won't vote to close, but a better place for this might be http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo application I use to demonstrate various aspects of DI in .NET, including [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx), Convention over Configuration, etc.

https://github.com/ploeh/Booking

While it's still demo code, it's intentionally created with a certain level of complexity to demonstrate exactly those things.

Answer (score 0):

There are two applications one [for Silverlight](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Silvertlight_Sample_App_Customer_contact_manager.ashx) and the other [for ASP.NET MVC](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx) that we have created to show how to use Castle Windsor container and demo some of its feature sets. Read more about it in the documentations.